# Undefined reference to vtable (Same old problem, few differences)

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I've searched the web for this and found the similar problem a bunch but I can't quite get it fixed with my code following all that information. I'm a total beginner.

I'm getting an `undefined reference to vtable for Character error`. Code below.

Character.h:

```
#ifndef CHARACTER_H_
#define CHARACTER_H_
#include "ZorkUL.h"
#include <QObject>

#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

class Character : public QObject {    
Q_OBJECT
private:
    int health;
    int stamina;
public:
    Character();
    void setHealth(void);
    void setStamina(void);   

signals:
    void listener();    
};    
#endif /*CHARACTER_H_*/
```

Character.cpp:

```
#include "Character.h"

Character::Character() {   
    this->health = 100;
    this->stamina = 100;
}

void Character::setHealth(void){    
    this->health = health - 10;
}

void Character::setStamina(void){    
    this->stamina = stamina - 10;
}

void Character::listener(){    
}
```

Comment: Just says "undefined reference to vtable for Character".

Comment: how do you compile all of this? Please post [MCVE]

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but after `using namespace std;`, `using std::vector;` doesn't add anything.

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: Unrelated, but **never** do `using namespace std;` in the global namespace in a header file.

Comment: I'm sorry guys I'm a little hopeless here, it's a program I've been given and to make additions and edits to so as to sort of learn what's going on. I'm getting errors in Character.cpp and Character.h. I do know that if I leave out the listener signal altogether it all compiles fine.

Comment: This is probably a compiling error, probably `Character.cpp` is not compiled or linked at the end. Please give us the full error message!

Comment: Does the program use threads?

Comment: No it doesn't use threads so far as I'm aware. Signals and slots and Q_OBJECT. It all compiles fine so long as I'm not declaring signals in my character class.

Comment: Oh, couid [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) be it? "_The Q_OBJECT macro is expanded by the preprocessor to declare several member functions that are implemented by the moc; if you get compiler errors along the lines of "undefined reference to vtable for LcdNumber", you have probably forgotten to [run the moc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html) or to include the moc output in the link command._"

Comment: Make sure that your project file(.pro) includes Character.h file in headers section. `HEADERS  += Character.h`

Comment: I mean that sounds like it's it Ted haha, I'm still as lost as ever though. It's definitely the macros that's giving me my error.

Comment: It seems like you are supposed to "_run the Meta-Object Compiler (moc)_" to avoid the problem. There's an instruction on the site too.

Comment: Cheers, Ted. I got it. Well, I Run->Cleaned All, the Built again.

Comment: Dunno does that count as solved haha.

Comment: @SeanBarrett I guess so - but I was just guessing so I think it's better if you write an answer to your own question. That's fine and will perhaps help others in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

After about a month of sifting through Google to find an answer to this issue, I finally was just now able to solve it.

Most answers will tell you to delete the build directory, or run `qmake` again and so on, and the idea behind this (highly simplified) is that QT's Meta Object Compiler generates additional `.cpp` files for classes with the `Q_OBJECT` macro in its class declaration, and can sometimes 'forget' to generate these files when additional files that use the `Q_OBJECT` macro have been added to the project.

While this is true in most cases, what solved the issue for me happened after *finally* inspecting the `mainwindow_moc.cpp` file myself.

Come to find out that an external Qt Widget I imported into my project (and had since stopped using, but forgot to take out the source files from my project) had some namespace declarations and `using` statements that seemed to confuse the MOC when generating my `mainwindow_moc.cpp` file.

As a result, the MOC generated my MainWindow functions scoped under this extra widget namespace, and the generated code that looked like `extra_namespace::MainWindow::staticMetaObject`, instead of `MainWindow::staticMetaObject`.

So the solution for me was to simply remove that widget from my `.pro` file, and all `#include` directives to those header files.

So if the first solution doesn't work for you, that is, deleting the build directory and running `qmake` manually.. take a look at the `classname_moc.cpp` files generated in your build directory and make sure the generated functions necessary for the `Q_OBJECT` macro are scoped properly.